# Folding a Given Net into a Polyhedron Automatically!

Tags: 3d, polyhedra

There are some applications to fold predefined nets into the polyhedra, e.g. ["Poly"](http://www.peda.com/poly/) or [this applet](http://illuminations.nctm.org/Activity.aspx?id=3521#AC).

Is there any application which automatically folds any net generated by the user, if possible?